# Returning assignable value for std::map() using overloaded [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdmap

I would like to insert data in my `Matrix` class using the `[]` operator. The argument of this operator, a `std::array<int, 2>`, is the key for the `std::map`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const int& rows, const int& cols)
    : rows(rows), cols(cols)
    {}

    std::map<std::array<int, 2>, T>& operator[] (std::array<int, 2> x) {
        return data[x];
    }

private:
    std::map<std::array<int, 2>, T> data;
    const int rows;
    const int cols;
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{

    Matrix<double> M(10, 10);

    M[{10, 10}] = (double) 10;

    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to return the reference to the map in a way that it is assignable, and keep getting the following error:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::map<std::array<int, 2>, double>' cannot bind
      to a value of unrelated type 'std::__1::map<std::__1::array<int, 2>, double,
      std::__1::less<std::__1::array<int, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::array<int, 2>,
      double> > >::mapped_type' (aka 'double')
        return data[x];
```

I got it working when returning a pointer to `data[x]`, dereferencing this and assigning a value to that. This does not deliver neat code, and I think it can be done more easily. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Type of `data[x];` is `T&`, did you mean to return that?

Comment: No, I'd like to return a reference to the map at key x, so that I can assign a value to it.

Comment: You don't want to return reference to a map. You want to return reference to *value in the map*.

Comment: you seem to confuse the mapped value and the key of the map.

Comment: That my friend, was the missing link! Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a map:

```
std::map<std::array<int, 2>, T>
```

then its `key_type` is `std::array<int,2>` and the `mapped_type` is `T`. `operator[]` takes a key and returns a reference to the corresponding value.

One correct way would be

```
T& operator[] (const std::array<int, 2>& x) {
    return data[x];
}
```

Or if you actually want `T` as keys and the arrays as values you rather need a

```
std::map<T, std::array<int, 2>>
```

and the method could be

```
std::array<int,2>& operator[] (const T& x) {
    return data[x];
}
```